# Why aren't there any timeline profiler for Java?

Tags: java, profiling

All of the profilers I've searched for (name a few: VisualVM, JProfiler, YourKit, async-profiler, and honest-profiler) doesn't support a simple timeline view, as Chrome Devtool or Unity profiler does. Any reason this *couldn't* be implemented on the java side?

[image: Timeline view on chrome devtool]

Comment: What would a timeline for a Java program show?

Comment: Just like what I see on chrome devtool: A timeline and a each java thread's stacktrace according to that timeline. For example unity has one (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html#timeline).

Comment: Clearly, it can't be "just like what I see on chrome devtool", because there isn't such thing as "Task" or "Event: mouseover" in general Java code. Note that the timeline doesn't show the time it takes to run _every_ JS function you wrote. In the Unity timeline as well, it shows very useful things such as "PlayerLoop" and "PhysicsProcessing", but not every C# method. This is why I asked you what you expect it to show. If you want the timeline to show when _every_ method is executed, that would be very impractical, as the answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Time lines views that show all method calls are not practical for Java programs because of the amount of data that has to be collected. Also, they are not generally useful because the data is hard to follow. Views that show cumulated stack traces (invocation trees, hot spot views, call graphs, flame graphs) are much more helpful for solving performance problems.

However, JProfiler has something similar with its call tracer view. It's not displayed as a timeline, but as a hierarchical tree of threads, packages, classes and actual method calls.

[image]

The screenshot above shows a measurement from a demo application. In a real-world application, this recording generates a lot of data and is capped to avoid excessive memory usage. As such, this feature is useful when combined with a trigger that records a short call trace for a special event.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.